# SQL Server - Remove ordered row pairs and keep only the pairs where the first row meet one criteria and the second row meet a second criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is sorted by apartment and then date. I want to keep everything the same, except for removing the pairs of apt rows that don't start with 2015 and end with 2019. Below is an example of input table and desired output.

Table (input):

```
apt   date          price
5B    4/13/2016     470000
5B    2/20/2019     2165000
15A   1/12/2015     2500000
15A   5/22/2019     1900000
28F   11/28/2016    621000
28F   12/11/2018    675000
PH     9/19/2015    6000000
PH     9/26/2019    4990000
3J     6/19/2015    615000
3J     5/15/2018    825000
```

Desired output:

```
apt   date          price
15A    1/12/2015    2500000
15A    5/22/2019    1900000
PH     9/19/2015    6000000
PH     9/26/2019    4990000
```

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming 'start' is the min date and 'end' is the max date you could just do something like this:

```
select x.* 
from #tmp x
inner join (select apt 
            from #tmp
            group by apt
            having year(min([date])) =  2015 
               and year(max([date])) = 2019 ) y
    on x.apt = y.apt
```